# Why the luatex85 package and the luatex manual does not share the same definitions for \pdf...?

Tags: luatex

One can read in the `luatex85` documentation:

> LuaTEX 0.85 and 0.87 contain many changes from LuaTEX 0.80 as
>   contained in TEXLive 2014. Most notably almost all the pdfTEX extended
>   primitves with names `\pdf...` have been renamed or removed.
>
> [...]
>
> The LuaTEX manual lists suitable compatibility definitions that may be
>   made so that documents can continue to use the old names. Mostly this
>   package just consists of those definitions, with minor changes in some
>   cases. (Mostly different choices over the use of \protected or \edef.)

Is there a reason other than "programming taste" for those different choices?

Comment: I fear this question has no constructive answer. We can be grateful about great products like luatex, even if the authors  willingly accept that end-users and package maintainers suffer from incompatible changes. So, we can make the following call to the luatex authors: "continue with the great work! And, if possible, please keep backwards compatibility even if your version number is below 1.0 --  we want to use your product".

Comment: As to your question: I suggest that you send an email to the authors of luatex and discuss these things in private. I would prefer that great package authors do not to feel as if they have to justify themselfes here. I vote to close this question.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Probably my bad English here. I meant no offence to luatex team. They know what they do. I was just wondering why the authors of `luatex85.sty` (the package) chose to change a little the definitions given in luatex manual to keep backwards compatibility, that is regarding ’\protected’ and ’\edef’ (last sentence cited). See e.g. `\def\pdffontname{\pdffeedback fontname}` (`luatex85.sty`) versus `\def\pdffontname{\numexpr\pdffeedback fontname\relax}` (`luatex` manual).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `luatex85` definitions have the advantage that they are in code and tested in more cases (used in the wild in latex) so work in more cases.

Several of the definitions were tweaked in the first few releases. Usually it doesn't matter too much whether you use `\def`  or `\edef` or whether or not you use `\protected`, and whether you terminate a number using a space or by `\numexpr...\relax`. But if you try the emulation in enough real world documents doing enough weird expansion contexts then you find that different commands need different types of emulation.

For example the case you mention in comments

```
\def\pdffontname{\pdffeedback fontname}              % (luatex85.sty)
\def\pdffontname{\numexpr\pdffeedback fontname\relax}% manual
```

In almost all cases this is going to be used as a number as in

```
\count@=\pdffontname
```

and either definition will work, but pdftex allows this to expand to a number in all contexts, and does not require `\the` so this plain tex document

```
\pdffontname\font

\bye
```

Is error free and typesets 1

The `\numexpr` version would produce

```
! You can't use `\numexpr' in vertical mode.
\pdffontname ->\numexpr 
                        \pdffeedback fontname\relax 
l.5 \pdffontname
              \font
?
```

unless you prefixed with `\the`

But the version without

```
\def\pdffontname{\pdffeedback fontname}

\pdffontname\font

\bye
```

does the right thing.

Sometimes as in

```
{\outputmode=1
         \xdef\pdfcreationdate   {\pdffeedback creationdate}
}
```

we work harder to expand to the right thing in one expansion step as someone had a real package that did

```
....\expandafter\something\pdfcreationdate
```

and `\something` needed to access the expanded date not just the first level expansion of `\pdffeedback creationdate`, and also pdftex makes this available in both PDF and DVI modes whereas the LuaTeX feedback is only available if `\outputmode` is 1.

It isn't clear that these considerations to make a robust emulation that works in the wild would necessarily clarify the manual which is giving the basic idea of how you might address the name changes that happened in LuaTeX 0.85, so we never thought it necessary to push these differences back to the LuaTeX team for the manual.

Comment: I would object to luatex85's \protected definition of \pdflastobj. It prevents storing its current value in a macro for later use. The same for \pdflastannot, which I need, for example, append to a list that is finally inserted as value to the /Fields key in the /AcroForm PDF dictionary. The definitions are not \protect-ed in the luaTeX manual.

Comment: @AlexG we'd take any difference in behaviour from pdftex as a valid bug report if you have an example (you are better placed to make examples I suspect:-) The good thing is the package has co-authors so any that are wrong we can blame the co author. does pdftex's `\pdflastannot` expand in an edef?, I could check I suppose....

Comment: I let expand \the\pdflastannot in pdfbase.sty, line 342.

Comment: @AlexG yes exactly, with `\the` so that should work here as well.

Comment: without the `\protected and without \the  then `\edef\something{... \pdflastannot..`  would expand `\pdflastannot` into its `\pdffeedback` expression so no longer a single token, unlike the pdftex version

Comment: Ah ok, does it mean that `\the` kind of overrides \protected? Maybe I should rely on the luatex85 definitions.

Comment: @AlexG yes as does `\expandafter`