# Graph Drawing with Tikz example error

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I have trouble making the Graph Drawing example on page 363 in the [TikZ & PGF](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) Manual work.

To this end, I've read the question asked ealier, [errors - Layered Graph From TikZ Manual #291718](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291693/layered-graph-from-tikz-manual/291718) but have not had any luck using the code suggested by user @JP-Ellis.

I'm getting the same error on my local install (MikTex 2.9 Fully updated, TexStudio 5.6.2) and on Overleaf.com

Here is my code example:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\title{Tikz Graph Test}
\begin{document}
\tikz [nodes={text height=.7em,text depth=.2em,draw=black!20,thick,fill=white,font=\footnotesize},>=stealth',rounded corners,semithick] \graph [layered layout,level distance=1cm,sibling sep=0.5em,sibling distance=1cm] {"Femte" -> {"Sjette","Prise"};};
\end{document}
```

- Here is the log from TexStudio ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2GhqHJFz))
- Here is the log from Overleaf ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mGwHuzUz))

The main errors seem to be these:

```
./main.tex:10: Undefined control sequence.
\sa@placebox ->\newpage \global \pdfpagewidth 
                                              =\wd \sa@box \global \pdfpageh...
l.10 ...tance=1cm] {"Femte" -> {"Sjette","Prise"};};
```

and this

```
! You can't use a prefix with `the character ='.
<to be read again>
=
l.10 ...tance=1cm] {"Femte" -> {"Sjette","Prise"};};
```

Comment: Load package `luatex85`.

Comment: That works. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Related link with some information https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354951/124842