# Animate and hyperref (form) packages incompatibility with LuaLaTeX?

Tags: hyperref, animate

Compiling a form with the `hyperref` package and in the presence of the `animate` package fails with LuaLaTeX one in two while it always works with PDFLaTeX.

Moreover, for an unknown reason (JavaScript implementation of Okular or of `hyperref` package?), that works only with Adobe Reader DC (on Linux via Wine/Snapd) and not with Okular.

Is there something I have missed?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
  \PushButton[name=myButton,
    borderwidth=1px,bordercolor={0 0 0},
    onclick={
      this.getField("myTextBox").value += 1;
    }
  ]{CLICK ME}
  \TextField[name=myTextBox,
    borderwidth=1px,bordercolor={0 0 0},readonly=true]{Counter}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okular support for JavaScript is very limited, just to make `animate` animations work, as far as I know.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks. Unfortunately that was what I guessed. Have you an idea about the main issue of the question?

Comment: Yes, I am working out an answer ;).

Comment: @AlexG Wonderful! ;-)

Comment: @AlexG your definition of \pdfpageref in pdfbase is wrong. You should use `\def\pdfpageref        {\pdffeedback pageref}` as in the luatex85 package.

Comment: @Ulrike Thank you. I will change this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in pdfbase. It gives \pdfpageref a faulty definition.
(It is also a bug in hyperref, it shouldn't use \pdfpageref with lualatex but directly the luatex primitive)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\def\pdfpageref{\pdffeedback pageref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\begin{Form}
\tracingmacros=1
  \PushButton[name=myButton,
    borderwidth=1px,bordercolor={0 0 0},
    onclick={
      this.getField("myTextBox").value += 1;
    }
  ]{CLICK ME}
  \TextField[name=myTextBox,
    borderwidth=1px,bordercolor={0 0 0},readonly=true]{Counter}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied that code in `pdfbase.sty` from the luatex manual. Thus, the luaTeX manual is wrong about this?

Comment: @AlexG I would say yes. \numexpr there looks like nonsense. You could ask David in the chat, he will know why he didn't use that in luatex85.

Comment: Maybe because pdfTeX's `\pdfpageref` expands immediately and the luaTeX manual's version requires `\the` before?

Comment: `\pdffeedback pageref 1` works fine and does the same as `\pdfpageref`.

Comment: This is what I already guessed in my previous comment. But what about the other replacements based on `\pdffeedback ...`. There are still a few of them with `\numexpr` before `\pdffeedback` in `luatex85.sty`.

Comment: @AlexG Ask David ...

Comment: @AlexG https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326293/why-the-luatex85-package-and-the-luatex-manual-does-not-share-the-same-definitio/354951#354951

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you for your prompt answer. Like for AiexG's response, it's a dilemma to choose between your two answers. But my incremental actual case works with your solution and not with the AlexG's one. Do have I to post a new question about my actual issue?

Comment: you should ask a new question. But in general: pdfmanagement-testphase comes with its own implementation of form fields, so I wouldn't use hyperrefs with it.

Answer (score 3):

If PDF forms are involved, `hyperref` and `animate` want to write on a number of global PDF objects concurrently.

Similar clashes may exist between other LaTeX packages that implement interactive PDF stuff. In order to resolve this, the LaTeX3 team is developing a common interface for package authors that enables them to write compatible PDF related code: [`pdfmanagement-testphase`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfmanagement-testphase). It is not yet included in the default LaTeX kernel and must be explicitly enabled:

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase} % load the package
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{} % activates the PDF management interface
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
  \PushButton[name=myButton,
    borderwidth=1px,bordercolor={0 0 0},
    onclick={
      this.getField("myTextBox").value += 1;
    }
  ]{CLICK ME}
  \TextField[name=myTextBox,
    borderwidth=1px,bordercolor={0 0 0},readonly=true]{Counter}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It's a dilemma to choose between Ulrike Fischer answer and yours. Both of them are working for this post but not for my actual intermediate case. Your solution fails and the one of Ulrike works. Do have I to post a new question?

Comment: I think that @Ulrike's answer fixes the real cause. I'd accept hers ;-)

Comment: @ejazz New version of `pdfbase` has arrived at CTAN. May take a day or so to show up in TeXLive.

Comment: Great news and useful as usual :-)